# Discord Bot announcement channel

Tags: javascript, discord

I want to make my discord bot make an announcement to a certain channel, based on the Channel ID.
I know how to make the bot respond in whatever channel it's talked to, using `message.channel.send()`, but I was wondering if there was a way to do `message.channelID.send()` to have the bot talk in a specific channel to make an announcement.

Thanks!
Nathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `client.channels.find("id", "what ever").send(/*...*/);` will work to send a message to a certain channel, but in the console, an alert is thrown. Using `client.channels.get("what ever").send("/*...*/");` does the same job, but without using a discord.js deprecated function.

Thanks to Jonas Wilms!

Answer (score 1):

```
 client.channels.find("id", "what ever").send(/*...*/)
```

All channels are stored in a [Collection](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection) under the [Client.channels](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=channels) prpperty which you can use to get it.

Comment: `(node:10152) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead` as a result of trying to use the announce function. It did work though!

Comment: Found the solution to the deprecated find function. `All collections used in Discord.js are mapped using their id property, and if you want to find by id you should use the get method. See MDN for details.` Using `client.channels.get("what ever").send("/ *...*/);` works the same, but won't throw a console error.